# document type does not allow element "script" here; assuming missing "body" start-tag

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I got this error after validation:

```
document type does not allow element "script" here; assuming missing "body" start-tag
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Feltöltött képek</title>
<!--getDyn       --><script type="text/javascript" src="js/my_js.js"></script>
<!--jQuery ERROR HERE--><script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<!--inFieldLabel --><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js"></script>
<!--Facebox      --><script type="text/javascript" src="src/facebox/facebox.js"></script>
<!--Modernizr    --><script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/swfupload/swfupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/swfupload/swfupload.queue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/swfupload/fileprogress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/swfupload/handlers.js"></script>
<!--IE plugins--><script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<!--cssReset     --><link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
<!--cssAll       --><link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--cssFacebox   --><link href="css/facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_tabla.css" />-->

<style type="text/css">...</style>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
</head>
<body  style="zoom:1; overflow:auto; min-width: 1058px;">...</body>
```

Could you tell me how to solve this?
Thanks!

Update:
I forgot, that the validator can't be logged in. -.-"
this was the tested source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>You have to login to contiune!</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>You have to login to contiune!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran it through the w3c validator "This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional! What is in the ...?
Result:  Passed, 1 warning(s)"

Comment: I think the issue may be in one of the `...` areas.

Comment: If I add `</html>` to the code above and paste it into the validator (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), it validates.

Comment: Amazing how the tested code shows the error, always post what you test in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second piece of code, your `<script>` tag is neither in `<head>` or `<body>`.
Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>You have to login to contiune!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>You have to login to contiune!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```